# redirect to url taken from json response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, redirect

I am using jquery ajax method to make http request to php webpage, and in response I am taking json like {"status":"success","url":"http url"}

on success function I am redirecting to url from json but most of the time it fails. I am using following to redirect:

```
window.location.href = url
```

It works fine when url is clean with no other characters, but fails when I have # or space or some other characters. Please letme know if there is any way to solve my problem.

Comment: Give a sample URL that fails...

Comment: I am using json_encode function on server side, so I think it is encoding special chars and creating something like &abc; for certain chars [link](http://example.com/post.php?s=Subject&p=1&t=Some_text_with_space and_quotation_and_hash)

Answer (score 6):

I personally use

```
    window.location.replace(url);
```

[Read More](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) - "*The replace() method replaces the current document with a new one*"
**window.location.replace()** better simulates a http redirect

There are other various options like:

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Which acts as a link click

Comment: window.location.replace(url); did not work as well. I am using json_encode function on server side, so I think it is encoding special chars, but I have no idea why window.location.replace(url) does not work, it should at least try to open that url, it it just does not do anything

Comment: sorry I thought what I have pasted would be enough. But I don't have my code with me right now. Tonight I will make a new post with my source code and some test cases that failed.

Comment: @jCloud You could just add the code to this post when you get a chance

Answer (score 2):

have u tried window.location = "url"

url should include http://

and it should be inside quotes

Answer (score 2):

if you use jquery it would be easier. here's an example:

```
function save(){
var item = "value of some input";
 $.ajax({
  url      : "process.php",
  dataType : "json",
  data     : "item ="+item,
  type     : "POST",
  cache    : false,
  success : 
  function (data){
// if the return of your json like {"status":"success","url":"http url"}
// use this
    if (data.status == "success"){
      window.location.href = data.url;
    }
    else{
      alert("error occured");
    }
  }
 });
}
```