# Knockout Form submission is not happening when html is binded

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, data-binding

I have a page which needs to be redirected to google mail page . Consider my JSON response is like below

```
var jsonResponse = {
'htmlData': '<html><head></head><body onLoad="document.myForm.submit()"><noscript><p>JavaScript is required. Enable JavaScript to use OAM Server.</p></noscript><form action="https://mail.google.com" method="post" name="myForm"></form></body></html>'
};
```

Which is binded to knockout html page like below . In the view model we will retrieve the information from json response

```
(viewModel.js)
public responseHtml: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>();
var response= jsonResponse.htmlData;
this.responseHtml(response); 

(view.html)
<div id="kk">
  <div id="data" data-bind="html: responseHtml"></div>
</div>
```

Here my rendering page is not getting redirected to gmail page , it is displaying a blank page. Could you let me know whether there is a way , where we can redirect to that url page.This view.html is rendered in popup window.

Comment: Perhaps this helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20089022/redirect-to-url-taken-from-json-response

Comment: @JoseLuis that helps when your html is not yet rendered. But here the html is rendered and then page should reload with the url, anyways i will try using window.location.replace

Comment: If you try to "insert" the GMail web page in the div 'data', I'm not sure you can do that.  If you submit a form to the GMail URl, then GMail should respond to this submit; I'm not sure it will respond.  Perhaps a link if a better approach than a form.

Comment: @JoseLuis Actually ,we dont have control over the json response. It is not possible for me to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json has an entire web page, starting with the  tag.  You can't insert this html inside a div.

If you are getting this json as a Ajax request, you could do this:

```
            $.ajax(
            {
                .. ,
                success: function (data) {
                    document.open();
                    document.write(data.htmlData);
                    document.close();
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.responseText);
                }
            });
```

This way you are "replacing" your actual web page with the one in the json response.